# How to combine purrr::map and sjmisc::frq to loop over weights?

Tags: r, purrr, weighted

I have a data frame with some target variables (i.e. v1 and v2) and some weights (i.e. wt1, wt2, wt3). I want to produce weighted frequencies of the target variables but using a weight each time. In other words, I want to replicate the frequency tables three times, using a different weight in each replication.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sjmisc)

 df <- tibble(v1 = rbinom(10, 1, .5), 
       v2 = rbinom(10, 1, .5), 
       wt_1 = runif(10, 0, 2), 
       wt_2 = runif(10, 0, 2), 
       wt_3 = runif(10, 0, 2)
       )
```

I have tried different approaches like:

```
df %>% 
  select(starts_with("wt_")) %>% 
  map(~frq(select(df, v1, v2), weights = .x))
```

This is the output I get alongside the unweighted frequencies (three times):

```
Weights `.x` not found in data.
Weights `.x` not found in data.
Weights `.x` not found in data.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frq` function wouldn't accept argument from outside of the dataframe. It needs `weight` to be part of the dataframe. Maybe there is a way but I couldn't figure it out.

Here is one way in which we can alternatively select weight columns and apply `frq` function. Find names of weight column,  `map` over them and `select` them alternatively along with `v1` and `v2` columns, rename it to some common name and then use that name in `frq` to assign weights.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sjmisc)

weight_names <- grep("wt_", names(df), value = TRUE)

map(weight_names, ~df %>% 
                   select(v1, v2, .x) %>% 
                   rename_at(3, ~"weight") %>%
                   frq(v1, v2, weights = weight))
```